# calling 2 different functions separately from one javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script like this:

*example.js*:

```
function ex1(){document.write('example1');}
function ex2(){document.write('example2');}

ex1();
ex2();
```

I want to use **ex1()** and **ex2()** from *example.js* in different places of my html page, and styling them differently.

So how can I call these **ex1()** and **ex2** separately in my html. Is it possible? If possible, how?

Thanks,

Comment: You seem to be thinking that `document.write` can be called directly in HTML and that it writes what you specified where you called it. You will consider DOM API for DOM manipulation or try jQuery. Then you willbea ble to write what you want, where you want.

Comment: If you want to add some text or html to the page you should look at the DOM API like the comment above states. I found this brief example of adding content to the page: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0460__DOM-Node/Createanelementfromdocument.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file referenced from your html, you can call these functions without any problem.

What do you mean by "styling" them though?
And what is the difference between the functions?

**EDIT** OP wants different styles for output in each function:

```
function ex1(){document.write('<p class="classone">example1</p>');}<br>
function ex2(){document.write('<p class="classtwo">example1</p>'');}
```

After that, modify your CSS like this:

```
.classone{
   // styles for the first
}

.classtwo{
   // styles for the second
}
```

Comment: i want example1 -- italic, red and example2 bold, blue

Comment: thanks and how can i call ex1() and ex2() separately from the html?

Comment: `<button onclick="ex1()" />` or `<button onclick="ex2()" />`

Comment: i don't want to use a button. Instead i want to see the string from ex1() in a specific place..

Comment: I think you lack the basic skills of Javascript and HTML. Please look for some tutorials on HTML and Javascript and try some things for yourself. W3Schools is a good place to start

Comment: i looked at w3schools and also i searched here.. i accept that i'm new but the problem is using the output of 2 functions (ex1(), ex2()) in different places. Have i to use always <button onclick> for calling something from a .js file?

Answer (score 0):

As a sort of quick explanation, `document.write` replaces the content of the page with whatever is inside the parantheses "`()`":

```
eg. document.write("hello world"); // Replaces everything with "hello world"
```

This is because the `document` part of the code refers to all the content in the body of the page (essentially everything that you see).

To put text in only a specific part of the page, you'll have to reference that item/element in which you want to place the text first. You can do this in a number of ways, such as referencing by element (as in @metal_fan's example), by class, element-type, etc. You can also use frameworks such as jQuery which specialize in referencing elements.

**jQuery version of @metal_fan's solution:**

```
eg. jQuery("#myId").html("hello world"); // Replaces content of #myId element with "hello world"
```

As *@Kenneth* implied (albeit a bit harshly), to use this well, you may need to increase your understanding of javascript and HTML. Might I suggest signing up for **[codingacademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/) turorials**? They are pretty comprehensive, you gain points, and its free.

Good luck!